# Declarators in C++

Tags: c++, declaration, language-lawyer

Whats the difference between an init-declarator and declarator in C++? An init-declarator may appear in init-declarator-list. Example:

```
int x, y, z;
```

or

```
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
```

where x, y, z may be the init-declarators or should i say declarators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the grammar:

> `init-declarator-list`:
>          `init-declarator`
>          `init-declarator-list , init-declarator`
>   `init-declarator`:
>          `declarator initializer`<sub>opt</sub>

That is, `init-declarator-list` **may** contain declaration of more than one variable, and `init-declarator` **must** contain declaration of exactly one variable.

That means, in your case, the first code is `init-declarator-list` and second code is `init-declarator` (and `init-declarator-list` both, since `init-declarator-list` may contain just one declaration).

But how does it matter what you call what? In everyday use, this difference is almost ignorable.

However, if you want to know about coding-style, then different people declare variables differently. I've seen many *good* programmers who use both style. I usually write all related variables in the same declaration-list, e.g

```
int x,y,z; //point coordinates
int height, width; //dimensions
std::string firstname, lastname; //name parts
int left, top, right, bottom; //rectangle coordinates
```

If you group them as above, it is easier for one to understand the meaning of each variables just by recognizing the group first. It is also easier to use just one comment for each declaration-list (exactly as I did above!) and you're done. It also helps maintenance to some extent, probably not that much though.

Comment: Pure style preference, but I like to group them yet still make distinct init-declarators for each variable/object, each on their own line.  If the names of the variables are not self-documenting, I place my comment directly above the grouping.

Comment: I think this only covers init-declarator, a declarator on the other hand has a very different meaning.